# Adding more than one entry_id

Tags: entryid

How can I add more than one entry to this. How do I add for more numerical ids?

{if:elseif entry_id == 216}

Answer (score 1):

You can use two pipes as an OR operator in EE conditionals:

```
{if:elseif entry_id == 216 || entry_id == 217 || entry_id == 218}
```

You can also use a plugin such as Switchee (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) if you have a large amount of conditionals.